# What qualifies as "extended discussion" needing moving to chat?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments, chat

After flagging [this answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31521/is-isis-made-by-the-usa/31538#31538) (I flagged the answer, not the comments, and wasn't complaining about the comments), the comments were moved into chat with the message "Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat."

Though there are a few comments made, as far as I can tell, almost all the comments were directly about the answer, rather than just general discussion about the topic asked about.

What qualifies as "extended discussion"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving all the comments to chat was the result of another flag, pointing out that there were a high number of comments on that answer. I believe I also cleared your flag on the answer at the same time.

The comments that I deleted were *not* discussing the answer, they essentially amounted to the OP telling you to do your own research and you (quite rightly) pointing out that citing evidence is the whole point of answering a question here on skeptics.

In review, there were a couple of comments which were directed towards improving the answer and/or refuting some of its points. Those have been re-instated as comments in order to drive potential improvement of this answer. I apologise for being a bit hasty, and perhaps being guilty of only skim-reading the comments.

Related: [Are a lot of comments being deleted on this SE?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/are-a-lot-of-comments-being-deleted-on-this-se)

Comment: You moved my comments to chat again, presumably by accident.